# Pass class implement interface into another constructor implement same interface?

Tags: java, javafx, interface

Couldnt find exactly same question/problem as i have, what i try to do is to pass a class as interface as argument into another class that also implements the same interface, see code below:

```
public class Combiner implements myInterface {

private final myInterface right;
private final myInterface left;

public Combiner(myInterface right, myInterface left) {
    this.right = right;
    this.left = left;
    System.out.println("In constructor");
}
```

From another class:

```
        try {
            MyInterface right = mine1.class.newInstance();
            MYInterface left = mine2.class.newInstance();
            Combiner comb = new Combiner(right, left);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

mine1:

```
public class mine1 implements MyInterface { .... }
```

mine2:

```
public class mine2 implements MyInterface { ..... }
```

MyInterface:

```
public interface MyInterface { }
```

Gets: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.livingcode.workflow.parts.HotspotSelectionChoice

Any ideas, whats wrong really?

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace();` (if you don't have proper logging) to see the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mine1.class.newInstance();
```

That's completely unncessary there and you need to instance then like

```
MyInterface right = new mine1();
MYInterface left = new mine2();
Combiner comb = new Combiner(right, left);
```

Note that Java class names starts with capital letter.